# Estimating GARCH parameters using Newton Raphson optimisation

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate the parameters for a GARCH(1,3) model using the following code below.

```
# choose the initial parameter values for the Newton Raphson optimization

a <- 0.2 # initial value for alpha
b1 <- 0.3 # initial value for beta1
b2 <- 0.1 # initial value for beta2
b3 <- 0.2 # initial value for beta3

omega <- var(SeP500)*(1-a-b1-b2-b3) # initial value for omega
omega
#Transform intitial values using the inverse of the link funtions
# This is done to avoid numerical problems in the optimization.
# The restrictions are the following: 
# - exp() to ensure omega>0
# - logistic()=exp()/(exp()) for 0<alpha<1
# - logistic()=exp()/(exp()) for 0<beta<1
# Therefore, we transform the parameter values with the inverse of these functions
# to give the desired initialization:

par_ini <- c(log(omega),log(a/(1-a)),log(b1/(1-b1)), log(b2/(1-b2)), log(b3/(1-b3)))

#Note that the numerical optimizer optim() minimizes a function. We want
#to maximize the log-likelihood. Therefore we need to provide a negative
#log-likelihood. Note also that for numerical reasons we optimize the
#average log-likelihood instead of the log-likelihood.

# Optim input:
# (1) Initial parameter (par): par_ini
# (2) Negative average log-likelihood function (fn): - llik_fun_GARCH()
# (3) Numerical algorithm used (method): BFGS

# fmincon output:
# (1) estimates: $par
# (2) log likelihood function value at theta_hat: $value
# (3) exit flag indicating convergence: $convergence

est <- optim(par=par_ini,fn=function(par)-llik_fun_GARCH(par,SeP500), method = "BFGS")

# Obtain parameter estimates
# est$par gives the values that maximize the likelihood
# However, these are not the paramter estimates since we have used the link functions
# to guarantee omega>0, 0<alpha<1 and 0<beta<1.
# Therefore, we apply these link functions to obtain the parameter estimates

omega_hat <- exp(est$par[1])
alpha_hat <- exp(est$par[2])/(1+exp(est$par[2]))
beta1_hat <- exp(est$par[3])/(1+exp(est$par[3]))
beta2_hat <- exp(est$par[4])/(1+exp(est$par[4]))
beta3_hat <- exp(est$par[5])/(1+exp(est$par[5]))

theta_hat <- c(omega_hat,alpha_hat,beta1_hat, beta2_hat, beta3_hat)
cat("The parameter estimates are:")
round(theta_hat,4)
```

The llik_fun_GARCH function is the following:

```
llik_fun_GARCH <- function(par,x){
  
  n <- length(x)
  
  #set paramter values from the input par using link functions for restrictions
  omega <- exp(par[1])                   #exp() to ensure omega>0
  alpha <- exp(par[2])/(1+exp(par[2]))   #logistic()=exp()/(exp()) for 0<alpha<1
  beta1 <- exp(par[3])/(1+exp(par[3]))    #logistic()=exp()/(exp()) for 0<beta1<1
  beta2 <- exp(par[4])/(1+exp(par[4]))    #logistic()=exp()/(exp()) for 0<beta2<1
  beta3 <- exp(par[5])/(1+exp(par[5]))    #logistic()=exp()/(exp()) for 0<beta3<1
  
  ## Filter Volatility
  sig2 <- rep(0,n)
  sig2[1] <- var(x) #initialize volatility at unconditional variance
  
  for(t in 2:n){
    sig2[t] <- omega + alpha*x[t-1]^2 + beta1*sig2[t-1] + beta2*sig2[t-2] + beta3*sig2[t-3]
  }
  
  ## Calculate Log Likelihood Values

  #construct sequence of log-likelihood contributions
  l <- -(1/2)*log(2*pi) - (1/2)*log(sig2) - (1/2)*x^2/(sig2)
  
  llik <- mean(l)  # obtain the average log-likelihood
  
  return(llik) # return the average log-likelihood as output
}
```

The problem I am encountering is that whenever I am running this code I keep getting this error:

```
est <- optim(par=par_ini,fn=function(par)-llik_fun_GARCH(par,SeP500), method = "BFGS")
Error in optim(par = par_ini, fn = function(par) -llik_fun_GARCH(par,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

It is not clear to me why I get this error I have tried some debugging but I was not able to solve the issue at hand.

The data that I used is the S&P500 returns historical data obtained from yahoo finance.

Comment: Do you have NA's in your data? Adding some of the data is important in addressing the problem here. Use `dput` and add the results to your post.

Comment: I used the returns from the S&P500 from the past 10 years. That data does not includes NA's also not after deriving the log returns

Comment: The reason that a minimal reproducible example is asked for is that it matters how you're using it. Are you using all of it? Open, close, and volume, low, and high? Did you modify it in any way? Is it a matrix, data frame, ts_tibble?